# How to supply values as objects to an annotation in Java

Tags: java, refactoring, mybatis

I'm working with mybatis, the next code is working:

```
@Select(GET_USER_DATA)
@Results(value = {
    @Result(property="webUserId",javaType=String.class,column="id_usuario_web"),
    @Result(property="webUserType",javaType=String.class,column="tipo_usuario_web"),
    @Result(property="webUserLastname",javaType=String.class,column="apellidos")
})
WebUser getUserData(@Param("login") final String login, @Param("password") final String password);
```

But I want to try something "better", so I tried this:

```
@Select(GET_USER_DATA)
@Results(value = {
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_ID.getResultObject()), 
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_TYPE.getResultObject()),
    @Result(WebUserTable.WEB_USER_LASTNAME.getResultObject())
})
WebUser getUserData(@Param("login") final String login, @Param("password") final String password);
```

for this I created this enum within my class:

```
enum WebUserTable{

    WEB_USER_ID("webUserId", Integer.class, "usuario_web_id"),
    WEB_USER_TYPE("webUserType", String.class, "tipo_usuario_web"),
    WEB_USER_LASTNAME("webUserLastname",String.class,"apellidos");

    private Object result;

    WebUserTable(final String _property, final Class _javaType, final String _column){
        result = new Object(){
            String property = _property;
            Class javaType = _javaType;
            String column = _column;
        };
    }

    public final Object getResultObject() {
        return result;
    }   

};
```

But I got this error `This attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Result` in the `@Result` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations only allow primitive data types, Strings, Class, enum, another annotation, or arrays of such.  Even though WebUserTable is an enum, to get to the specifics requires a method call and annotations can't do that.

In some respects, annotation processing is not doing much more than simple substitution, I often use C #defines to make sure I don't go too nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations in Java are static (they must be completely defined at compile-time).
Hence only primitive types, Strings, enums and classes can be added as annotations values.

In your example, you are calling `getResultObject()` method in the annotation definition. It is rejected by the compiler because it is not defined at compile-time.